# Can a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}2)^n=1$ be infinitely substituted into itself?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

**Example**

$$\Large\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{...}2\right)^n}2\right)^n}2\right)^n}2\right)^n}2\right)^n$$

**Motivation**

Recently did a screen share on [gather.town](https://gather.town/) with itself and was greeted with this image below. The idea popped into my head, "What if this infinite mirror concept was applied to an infinite series, would it be possible to create a series that has a known result but is not calculable?"

[image: infinity_mirror]

Comment: yes without using the sigma notation but what is the motivation for your question?

Comment: $$\Large\sum_{n=\sum_{n=\dots}^{\infty} (\frac{\dots}2)^n}^{\infty} (\frac{\sum_{n=\sum_{n=\dots}^{\infty} (\frac{\dots}2)^n}^{\infty} (\frac{\dots}2)^n}2)^n$$

Comment: I mean, you could, but you have to be very careful using "${\dots}$"... if I wanted to try and actually evaluate the expression you have just given, what rules would I follow? With infinite sums, there is some partial sum approximation I can do to get an approximate answer to expression, but here it's not clear you could actually begin to evaluate the expression without knowing what should be at the end of the "${\dots}$"

Comment: Perhaps this is the start of series sigma art or obfuscation? ;)

Comment: Excute this code to see is my excellent art: ```$\Large\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{...}2\right)^n}2\right)^n}2\right)^n}2\right)^n}2\right)^n$```

Comment: A thing of beauty!

Comment: I suppose you need to be careful about summation over $n$ multiple times. You need new variables.

Comment: IMO, this notation is meaningless, because the $\cdots$ have no explicit beginning.

Comment: Obviously adding $41$ to that series notation yields $42$ which gives an "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you end up with is the relation

$$x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n.$$

If we assume $x$ to be complex we must have $|x| < 2$ or the RHS diverges. Then, summing the geometric series

$$x = -1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n$$
$$x = -1 + \frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}x^2 +\frac{1}{2}x = 0$$

gives $x = 0 \vee x = 1$ as the only solutions.